# How to accept the work item as "completed" in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I am confused on how to accept the work item when the State is set to "Done" by developer. I would like to review it prior to it being transferred to the "Done" state by developer. Is the reassignment of the work item to me by the developer the only way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '**Completed**' generally is a state category that could contains the following states by default:

- **`Done`**
- **`Closed`**
- **`Inactive`**
- **`Completed`**

On different work item types, the default states under the '**Completed**' category might be different.

---

For your case, if you want to review the work items before moving to **`Done`** state, you can try like as below:

1. Ensure the process that is in use by your project is an [inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process). If not, try to [create an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) from the default process that is currently in use by your project. Then [change the project process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-agile-to-scrum?view=azure-devops#change-the-project-process) to the inherited process.
2. Open the inherited process, then find and open the work item type you need to review.
3. On the '**States**' tab, you can create a new state (e.g., **`Review`**, **`Need-Review`**, **`Reviewing`** or any other names you prefer) to the state category before '**Completed**' category. The category before '**Completed**' might be '**Resolved**' category or '**In Progress**' category in different work item types.

   **Note:** The '**Completed**' category can only have one enabled state at the same time. If you create a new state to this category, the existing state under it will be disabled (hide) and not available. That's why you need to create the new states to the category which is before '**Completed**' category.
4. After above configuration, you can inform the developers move the work items to the new state instead of "**`Done`**" state if need your review. After you complete the review, you can move the work items to "**`Done`**" state.

---